# About Poisson Equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to solve $ - \Delta u = f$ in $\Omega$ with $u = \phi $ on $ \partial \Omega$. But if I have the solutions of (1) and (2) below : $$ - \Delta u_1 = f \; \text{in } \Omega , \; u_1 = 0  \; \text{on } \partial \Omega \tag{1}$$ $$ - \Delta u_2 = 0 \; \text{in } \Omega , \; u_2 = \phi  \; \text{on } \partial \Omega \tag{2}$$ Then how can I solve the problem  $ - \Delta u = f$ in $\Omega$ with $u = \phi $ on $ \partial \Omega$  by using $u_1 , u_2 $ ?

Comment: Hint: The Laplacian $\Delta$ is a *linear* operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is $v=u_1+u_2$. In fact, we have
$$ -\Delta v=  -\Delta u_1 - \Delta u_2 = f \quad \mbox{in} \Omega$$
and 
$$ v= 0 +\phi = \phi\quad \mbox{on} \quad \partial  \Omega.$$